# Tabbed browsing of documents in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, tabs, microsoft-office-2003

Is there any way to enable tabbed browsing of documents in Microsoft Word (at least in Office 2003) like we see in EditPlus or TextPad?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with [**OfficeTabs**](http://hi.baidu.com/officecm/blog/item/19de9c6dcf6276f2431694b0.html).

[image]

Read more about it [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/07/officetab-add-on-tab-feature-for-microsoft-office/).

Answer (score 1):

With Office Tab, you can bring tabbed browsing to Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

[Office Tab](http://www.extendoffice.com/)

[image]

Comment: Is this a seperate product from OfficeTabs?